# Where can I find detailed reference info for object methods?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script. Cmdlets like `Remove-Item` are easy to find reference information for; you can type `help Remove-item` in PS.

However, in some cases, you would like to be able to use the `$item.Delete()` method instead of the `Remove-Item` cmdlet. E.g. I've read that's the way to delete files without having them go into the Recycle Bin first.

But how do we find detailed reference information about the file object's `Delete` method? The closest I've come is something like

```
PS C:\> dir E:\blue.html | Get-Member
   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition                                  
----                      ----------     ----------                                  
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}               
...
Delete                    Method         void Delete()
```

which tells me that the FileInfo type *has* a `Delete()` method, and gives me its signature (no parameters, apparently). But where do I find out about the semantics of this method? E.g. does it really bypass Recycle Bin, always? If there are no parameters, is there no way to get it to remove a folder (`-Recurse`)? Etc.

Of course I'm really hoping for an online reference, rather than a link to a book I have to buy.

Comment: You could always start by dropping [System.IO.FileInfo](https://www.bing.com/search?q=system.io.flieinfo) into a search engine and see what comes out.  You'll be surprised.

Comment: Good idea. @RyanBemrose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is based on .net System.IO.FileInfo is a .net object and you can find all the documentation for it on MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx